# How to read unspaced-intergers from a file into an array in c++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to read a 1000 digit number digit by digit into a 1000 member array and am unable in finding how. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi, read a digit as a character subtract '0' (0x30) from it and store it as a integer.

Comment: What have you tried?  oops, too late.  It seems you have already been successful getting someone else to write your code.

Comment: I'm sorry. Didn't really want someone to write my code for me. Just needed an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should read individual digits as characters and convert character codes into digits.

```
#include <iostream>

const int n = 1000;

int main(void){
  char c;
  int digits[n];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      std::cin >> c;  
      digits[i] = c-0x30;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That conversion should be `c - '0'`. As written it's ASCII-centric; subtracting `'0'` is required to work for all character encodings.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Read the character literal using the  [basic_stream::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function and convert it into an integer number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    std::fstream fs("myfile.txt");
    char c;
    int arr[1000];
    int counter = 0;
    while (fs.get(c)){
        arr[counter] = static_cast<int>(c - '0');
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Error checking omitted. Prefer vector to array.

Comment: Don't really know how to use vectors. Still, thanks for the help.